# What permissions does _www have?

Tags: macos, apache, permissions, file-permissions, osx-server

Trying to find out what permissions user '_www' has on my OS X server. I need to find out if it has root access, if it could access any system files or if it can simply access the standard top level 'Websites' directory for Writes.

Comment: Usually only root has `root`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can look in `/etc/group` to see which groups `_www` belongs in:

```
$ grep _www /etc/group
_www:*:70:_devicemgr,_teamsserver
```

On a properly configured server, the whole point of running the web server as a dedicated user is to limit that user's privileges elsewhere.  However, web application code which accesses the filesystem is capable of reading outside the server's DocumentRoot.

Therefore, any file not owned by `_www` but for which it has read permissions and execute on the file's parent directory could in theory be read by `_www` if the application code doesn't protect against that while reading the filesystem.  Likewise, files on the filesystem which are other-writable could be modified by the web server if the application code provides access to them.

Such issues are exploitable when an application uses user input to generate a file path for reading or writing, but fails to guard against input like : `../../../../../../../../../` which, when possibly coupled with a [NULL byte injection](http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection) could produce filenames in the application like

```
/www/application/phptemplates/../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd
```

Of course, on a modern system, `/etc/passwd` doesn't actually store passwords, but it may reveal local users and other valued info to a potential attacker.